# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: java, websphere, slf4j

My application is to be deployed on both tcServer and WebSphere 6.1. This application uses ehCache and so requires slf4j as a dependency.
As a result I've added the slf4j-api.jar (1.6) jar to my war file bundle.

The application works fine in tcServer except for the following error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

However, when I deploy in WebSphere I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder`.

Also accompanied by `Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder"`

I've checked the classpaths of both application servers and there is no other slf4j jar.

Does anyone have any ideas what may be happening here?

Comment: This [article](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/slf4j/solving-failed-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error/) solved my problem

Comment: I have answered this question here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66954369/13898185

Answer (score 870, accepted):

I had the same issue with WebSphere 6.1. As Ceki pointed out, there were tons of jars that WebSphere was using and one of them was pointing to an older version of slf4j.

The No-Op fallback happens only with slf4j 1.6+ so anything older than that will throw an exception and halts your deployment.

There is a documentation in [SLf4J site](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder) which resolves this. I followed that and added `slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar` to my application along with `slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar` which I already had.

If you use Maven, add the following dependencies, with `${slf4j.version}` being [the latest version of slf4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api)

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This solved my issue.

Comment: Yes, the error goes as also mentioned here - http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html But i get a new error now - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

Comment: "As Ceki pointed out, there were tons of jars that WebSphere was using and one of them was pointing to a older version of slf4j." - So much for Maven taking care of dependencies! What a joke.

Comment: Hey you MAVEN users: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.6.2

Comment: I'm using 1.7 and has the same problem. I add slf4j-simple-1.7.jar and now the problem solved.

Comment: @Sergio maven solution is not working on jenkins Linux box. But it does work on local machine , not sure what may be going wrong ?

Comment: @Sergio's maven xml should be included in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: It worked for me with the version 1.7.25 when I encountered the issue in android environment. @Edenshaw It's been said in other answers. I also created one for gradle.

Comment: Not a very good answer - why not explain the solution instead of using a link which doesn't do that great of a job explaining it

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The slf4j-simple jar doesn't pick up the log4j.properties. Instead, I use the implementation by adding slf4j-log4j12 and log4j jar, which works well for me.

Comment: My comment doesn't deserve its own answer but make sure that the scope isn't just set to test. (<scope>test</scope>; don't do this)

Comment: I am using ktor-wbsockets in my android app in Kotlin and I got same error. Could you please help me how do I import slf4j to my app?

Comment: slf4j-simple has slf4j-api as dependecy, so you need just that

Comment: What do sbt users do?

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Instead of the errors, I started seeing log messages.

Answer (score 478):

This is for those who came here from Google search.

If you use Maven just add the following

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Or

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for `slf4j-simple` not to be the same version as `slf4j-api`? They would probably work well together, but I think it is safer and a better practice in general to have them use the same version. Also, if you need to enable console-only logging, for instance, when running unit tests, then `slf4j-simple` seems to be enough (it was for me though).

Comment: AFAIK you should have just 1 impl of slf4j, i.e. either slf4j-log4j12 OR slf4j-simple, not both.

Comment: @Igor KatKov this works only on local machine but getting same error on Jenkins not sure what is going wrong. can you please clarify

Comment: slf4j-api requires configuration which is not available when you first run it (and haven't edited any configuration files). Using slf4j-simple will allow you to use basic Logger without configuring any files but WYSIWYG. You can then move back to slf4j-api once you have learned to configure the files and customize the Logger output how you like. (Still learning where there are and how to edit them myself)

Comment: Second dependency worked for me. First one created another warning *WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.semanticweb.owlapi.utilities.Injector).*

Comment: It still doesn't work after countless variations of adding these two dependencies, slf4j-api and slf4j-simple .

Answer (score 110):

Simply add this to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The solution worked for me; It is worth pointing to the documentation (where I found the error explained): http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder

Comment: nothing else but this worked for me while running a simple kafka producer example. thanks a bunch!

Comment: @WitoldKaczurba is right. I was having the same issue while using dependency using maven. I just googled and went to http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder which states the problem and its solution. I was using slf4j-api version 1.7.25. After checking documentation on mentioned link I just used <dependency> 
            `<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId> 
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>` and problem was resolved

Comment: I don't understand the point of using Maven if libraries which need some logger (e.g. Handlebars which needs slf4j) don't declare it in their pom. Anyway : thank you.

Comment: In my case, this is not solution. It is only hide information, that there are incompatible versions of slf4j and log4j or another plugin.

Comment: Seems to be version specific. This also solved the issue for me.

Comment: Applying this dependency removed the error message, but resulted in a swarm of unwanted kafka logs appearing in my terminal

Answer (score 67):

Quite a few answers here recommend adding the slf4j-simple dependency to your Maven POM file. You might want to check for the most current version.

At https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple
you'll find the latest version of the SLF4J Simple Binding. Pick the one that suites you best (still 1.7.32 from 2021-07  is the stable version as of 2021-10) and include it to your `pom.xml`.

For your convenience some dependencies are shown here - but they might not be up-to-date when you read this!

**Alpha Version of 2024-01**

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0-alpha1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Stable Version 2024-02**

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I removed the scope test part thanks to the comment below.

Comment: why do you use `<scope>test</scope>`? In my experience, I at least need `runtime` scope to ensure the `slf4j-simple` is on the classpath. Curious how you got this to work with only `test` scope...

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I removed the scope tag from my answer accordingly. It was a cut&paste issue - the link I am supplying provides the beta dependency this way.

Answer (score 52):

You need to add following jar file in your classpath: `slf4j-simple-1.6.2.jar`. If you don't have it, please download it. Please refer to http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings

Answer (score 44):

Sometime we should see the note from the warnin `SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.`.

> This happens when no appropriate SLF4J binding could be found on the class path

You can search the reason why this warning comes.
Adding one of the jar from `*slf4j-nop.jar`, `slf4j-simple.jar`, `slf4j-log4j12.jar`, `slf4j-jdk14.jar` or `logback-classic.jar*` to the class path should solve the problem.

```kotlin
// build.gradle

dependencies {
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1")
}
```

for example add the above code to your `build.gradle` or the corresponding code to `pom.xml` for maven project.

Answer (score 34):

I was facing same error. I have configured slf4j-api, slf4j-log4j12 and log4j, in my local development. All configuration was fine, but slf4j-log4j12 dependency which I copied from mvnrepository had test scope `<scope>test</scope>`. When I removed this every thing is fine.

Some times silly mistakes breaks our head ;)

Answer (score 16):

put file `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar` in the classpath will do the trick.

Comment: or add the dependency into your pom

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 12):

SLF4j is an abstraction **for various logging frameworks**. Hence apart from having slf4j you need to include any of your logging framework like log4j or logback (etc) in your classpath. 
To have an idea refer the *First Baby Step* in http://logback.qos.ch/manual/introduction.html

Comment: Adding logback fixed this for me. I dropped latest logback classic into pom (1.1.7) and it failed because slf4j dependency was too old (1.6.2). Downgrading logback to 1.0.0 and leaving slf4j at 1.6.x worked, as did upgrading slf4j to 1.7.20 and leaving logback at 1.1.7.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Maven to dependency management so you can just add following dependency in `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

For non-Maven users
Just download the library and put it into your project classpath.

Here you can see details: http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder/

Comment: Also for maven users I found that I needed to add the following into pom.xml, which also brings in logback-core automatically:  <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: `This is not an error. This message tells you that you do not have any logger implementation (such as e.g. Logback) added in classpath, and therefore NOP (No Operation) log`
[Look for sarxos comment](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/issues/278) as mentioned by @Paul need to add logback-classic.


Another approach of change to `<artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>` from `<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>` also does the work. It is illustrated [here](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.sg/2013/08/how-to-configure-slf4j-with-different.html)

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the similar problem with Spring-boot-2 applications with Java 9 library.

Adding the following dependency in my pom.xml solved the issue for me:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.slf4j-maven-plugin-log</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-maven-plugin-log</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: why this is required, it is not nice, what does google code do with this lib :)

Answer (score 10):

I got into this issue when I get the following error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

when I was using `slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar` in my `libs`.

Inspite I tried with the whole suggested complement jars, like `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar`, `slf4j-simple-1.7.5` the error message still persisted. The problem finally was solved when I added `slf4j-jdk14-1.7.5.jar` to the java libs.

Get the whole slf4j package at http://www.slf4j.org/download.html

Answer (score 7):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Put above mentioned dependency in `pom.xml` file

Comment: But remember to check the latest version.

Answer (score 6):

Slf4j is a facade for the underlying logging frameworks like log4j, logback, java.util.logging.

To connect with underlying frameworks, slf4j uses a binding.

- log4j - `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar`
- java.util.logging - `slf4j-jdk14-1.7.21.jar` etc

The above error is thrown if the binding jar is missed. You can download this jar and add it to classpath.

For Maven dependency,

```xml
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency in addition to `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar`, it will pull `slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar` as well as `log4j-1.2.17.jar` into your project.

Reference: http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html

Answer (score 6):

Please add the following dependencies to pom to resolve this issue.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.25</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I just included the first dependency - as pointed in another answer - and it works. Both dependencies do not solve the problem for me.

Comment: And want to use local maven instead of Bundled maven of Intellij.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to the jar inclusion and pure maven solutions, you can include it [from maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple) with gradle.

### Example for version `1.7.25`

```java
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple
    api group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.25'
}
```

Put this within the dependencies of your `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 5):

In the Websphere case, you have an older version of slf4j-api.jar, 1.4.x. or 1.5.x lying around somewhere. The behavior you observe on tcServer, that is fail-over to NOP, occurs on slf4j versions 1.6.0 and later. Make sure that you are using slf4j-api-1.6.x.jar on all platforms and that no older version of slf4j-api is placed on the class path.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked my WebSphere 6.1 classpath and I do not see any other version of slf4j e.g. I did a search on my WebSphere filesystem for *slf4j*jar and I only got my 1.6 version returned. Do you know if WebSphere comes packaged with slf4j?

Comment: Anything is possible but I'd be very surprised if WebSphere came bundled with slf4j-api. Weld bundles slf4j-api.jar. Are you using Weld?

Answer (score 3):

I am working in a project Struts2+Spring. So it need a dependency `slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar`.

If I run the project, I am getting error like

**Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"**

I solved my problem by adding the `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar`.

So add this jar in your project to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

As [SLF4J Manual](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) states

> The Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade
> or abstraction for various logging frameworks, such as
> java.util.logging, logback and log4j.

and

> The warning will disappear as soon as you add a binding to your class path.

So you should choose which binding do you want to use.

**NoOp binding (slf4j-nop)**

> Binding for NOP, silently discarding all logging.

Check fresh version at https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.slf4j%20AND%20a:slf4j-nop&core=gav

**Simple binding (slf4j-simple)**

> outputs all events to System.err. Only messages of level INFO and higher are printed. This binding may be useful in the context of small applications.

Check fresh version at https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.slf4j%20AND%20a:slf4j-simple&core=gav

**Bindings for the logging frameworks (java.util.logging, logback, log4j)**

You need one of these bindings if you are going to write log to a file.

See description and instructions at https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#projectDep

---

*My opinion*

I would recommend ***Logback*** because it's a successor to the *log4j* project.

Check latest version of the binding for it at https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:ch.qos.logback%20AND%20a:logback-classic&core=gav

You get console output out of the box but if you need to write logs into file just put `FileAppender` configuration to the `src/main/resources/logback.xml` or to the `src/test/resources/logback-test.xml` just like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
           <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>logs/logs.log</file>
         <encoder>
             <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

    <logger level="DEBUG" name="com.myapp"/>
</configuration>
```

(See detailed description in manual: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)

Answer (score 3):

**As per the SLF4J Error Codes**

Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
This warning message is reported when the org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class could not be loaded into memory. This happens when no appropriate SLF4J binding could be found on the class path. Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem.

Note that slf4j-api versions 2.0.x and later use the [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) mechanism. Backends such as logback 1.3 and later which target slf4j-api 2.x, do not ship with org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder. If you place a logging backend which targets slf4j-api 2.0.x, you need slf4j-api-2.x.jar on the classpath. See also [relevant faq](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#changesInVersion18) entry.

**SINCE 1.6.0** As of SLF4J version 1.6, in the absence of a binding, SLF4J will default to a no-operation (NOP) logger implementation.

If you are responsible for packaging an application and do not care about logging, then placing slf4j-nop.jar on the class path of your application will get rid of this warning message. Note that embedded components such as libraries or frameworks should not declare a dependency on any SLF4J binding but only depend on slf4j-api. When a library declares a compile-time dependency on a SLF4J binding, it imposes that binding on the end-user, thus negating SLF4J's purpose.

Comment: I only have slf4j version 1.7.32 in my pom from the beginning but still this problem occurs.

Comment: What do you mean by class path?

Comment: @user1034912 all Java applications have a list of packages from which to search for classes - the list is called the class path can can be edited with IDEs such as Eclipse and IntelliJ.

Answer (score 3):

this can resolve using the same version. I tried this and solved it

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html) official documentation

> **Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder**
>
> This warning message is reported when the
>   org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class could not be loaded into
>   memory. This happens when no appropriate SLF4J binding could be found
>   on the class path. ***Placing one (and only one)*** of slf4j-nop.jar,
>   slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or
>   logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem.

Simply add [this jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.6.1/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar) along with slf4j api.jar to your classpath to get things done.
Best of luck

Answer (score 2):

I added this dependency to resolve this issue:

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.25
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your problem was because of `<scope>test</scope>` (in some cases also `<scope>provided</scope>`), as mentioned [@thangaraj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49098287/8370915).

[Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) says:

> This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal
> use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation
> and execution phases. [**Test dependencies aren’t transitive and are only present for test and execution classpaths.**](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-scopes)

So, if you don't need dependencies for test purposes then you can use instead of (what you will see in [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.7.24)):

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.24</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Without any scopes (by default would be *compile scope* when no other scope is provided):

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop -->
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the same as:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop -->
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are my 5 cents...

I had the same issues while running tests. So I've fixed it by adding an implementation for the test runtime only. I'm using gradle for this project.

> // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic
>
> testRuntimeOnly group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic',
> version: '1.2.3'

Comment: For logback lovers attention to this answer! (it's also default logger for spring-boot as of now)

Answer (score 2):

encountered the same problem on payara 5.191

jcl-over-slf4j together with slf4j-log4j12 solved the problem

```xml
<properties>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.29</slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>        

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

for me the total fix was:

1. Add slf4j dependencies

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.5</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.5</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. create file `log4j.properties`, and add inside:

   ```
   # Root logger option
   log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

   # Direct log messages to stdout
   log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
   log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
   ```

otherwise I got some exceptions in the console.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I replaced `log4j-slf4j-impl` with `log4j-slf4j2-impl` when doing an upgrade of the dependencies, which caused the error message.
Reverting to slf4j (without the '2') solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it adding this library: slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar
You can download this in official web https://www.slf4j.org/download.html

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was:
Using Hibernate, I saw that it already used slf4j, and it was in my classpath already, so I decided to use it.
The next step - adding implementor for slf4j, so I added to Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

But it failed with error! `SLF4J: Failed to load class “org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder”`

The solution was:
Hibernate's dependency of slf4j was version **1.7.26**, and I added minor version dependency **1.7.25**. So when I fixed this - all became OK

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading logback-classic to latest version: 1.4.5, I ran into this issue `SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"` . logback-classic:1.4.x don't have class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder and hence the issue.

FYI: slf4j-api 2.0.x will no longer search for StaticLoggerBinding. Refer to https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#changesInVersion200 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a little old, but in case anyone else runs into this problem:

Add slf4j-jdk14-X.X.X.jar to your CLASSPATH (where X.X.X is the version number - e.g. slf4j-jdk14-1.7.5.jar).

HTH
Peter

Comment: Are you suggesting that users should revert to JDK1.4 logging to resolve a classpath issue? Also look at this FAQ entry: http://slf4j.org/faq.html#need_to_recompile

Answer (score 0):

I use Jena and I add the following dependence to `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency> 
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

I try to add slf4j-simple but it just removed the `SLF4J: Failed to load class “org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder”` error but logback-classic showed more detail information.

The [official document](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)

Answer (score 0):

the solution is indicated on their official website :

> Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
>
> This warning message is reported when the
>   org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class could not be loaded into
>   memory. This happens when no appropriate SLF4J binding could be found
>   on the class path. Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar
>   slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or
>   logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem. SINCE
>   1.6.0 As of SLF4J version 1.6, in the absence of a binding, SLF4J will default to a no-operation (NOP) logger implementation. If you are
>   responsible for packaging an application and do not care about
>   logging, then placing slf4j-nop.jar on the class path of your
>   application will get rid of this warning message. Note that embedded
>   components such as libraries or frameworks should not declare a
>   dependency on any SLF4J binding but only depend on slf4j-api. When a
>   library declares a compile-time dependency on a SLF4J binding, it
>   imposes that binding on the end-user, thus negating SLF4J's purpose.

solution : I have added to my project using maven research on intellij and i have chosen the slf4j-jdk14.jar.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and it got resolved by doing the following:

1. File -> Project Structure...
2. Module -> Dependencies
3. New Library -> From Maven -> Search for: slf4j.nop
4. Click on the latest version -> Apply

Comment: This will pull the no-logging version of SLF4j that doesn't log anything.

Answer (score 0):

Android dev here. For me it was upgrading to Amplify version 2.4.1 that broke the logback-android.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue and after some hustle Placing one **(and only one)** of slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem

While I had to supply logback-classic.jar, still need to ensure correct version of logback-classic.jar, logback-core.jar be provided.

[image]

https://logback.qos.ch/dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are using Spring Boot, that project is already bundling all the SLF4J dependencies, meaning listing them directly in your Maven project will not work since there will be different versions of your logging packages if you do that.

Spring Boot ships with Logback and log4j support, where Logback is the one which is enabled by default. So if you want to use log4j for logging, the only dependencies you need for that are the following:

```xml
    <!-- This is the latest version at the time of writing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ... other dependencies ... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you want to use Logback instead of log4j you have to remove the `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` dependency and also delete the `spring-boot-starter-logging` exclusion.

Comment: Can you look https://stackoverflow.com/q/78028371/14686302. I couldnt fix my problem

Answer (score -2):

I did not add any dependencies, I just change the way I was consuming them.

#### Preview code

(Uncomment this code if you are using elastic search version < 7.0)

```
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(
  "twitter",
  "tweets",
  id // this is to make our consumer idempotent
).source(record.value(), XContentType.JSON);
```

#### Current code

```
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("tweets")
  .source(record.value(), XContentType.JSON)
  .id(id); // this is to make our consumer idempotent
```

I am using bulkrequest and with that I remove that error.

Comment: How's this related to the slf4j issue?