# Packr not working

Tags: windows, export, libgdx, packr

I want to export my LibGDX game, but when I try to run packr with this config:

```
{
"platform": "windows",
"jdk": "openjdk-1.7.0-u45-unofficial-icedtea-2.4.3-windows-i586-image.zip",
"executable": "LibGDX",
"appjar": "LibGDX5.jar",
"mainclass": "cz/vilix/main/Desktop",
"vmargs": [
   "-Xmx1G"
],
"resources": [

],
"minimizejre": "soft",
"outdir": "out"
}
```

I get this output in the console:

[image: Console output]

But everything seems to be in place:

[image: Required files]

And I get the following output in the 'out' directory (obviously, running the 42KB exe file doesn't work):

[image: Out folder]

This is the content of the .jar file:

[image: Content of jar]

I think it might not be working due to not specifying res folder, but I don't know to fix it.

### UPDATE:

I've tried creating a new xml file pom.xml, which contains this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.badlogicgames.packr</groupId>
    <artifactlId>packr</artifactlId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

changed the config.json to contain this:

```
"resources": [
    "pom.xml"
],
```

The output folder looks the same, except there is the pom.xml file included. And also now I get this error:

[image: New error]

Comment: It wasn't mentioned in the guide. I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Rather use packr-1.3-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar, you can use mine: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/tuer/code/pre_beta/lib/ant/packr-1.3-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues..

The slf4j library would come from the Maven dependecy from the pom.xml

The pom.xml would look like

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.badlogicgames.packr</groupId>
  <artifactlId>packr</artifactlId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you look at the Packr Readme you notice that you specificy the pom.xml either when calling the JAR or set as a config

```
java -jar packr.jar .... -resources pom.xml ...
```

or in config.json

```
{

  ...
  ...

  "resources": ["pom.xml"],

  ...
}
```

Read the readme and follow it to fix the issues https://github.com/libgdx/packr

Comment: I've read it before (and read it again now), but still have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: First, it is looking for $RECYCLE_BIN environment variable then trying to parse the contents, but it is failing and I am not 100% sure why.  But the slf4j class not found issue can be resolved if you include the pom.xml to get the required JARs with Maven.

Comment: Where should I include the pom.xml?

Comment: That is, I believe, is just a warning about the logger.  The JAR seems to continue to process.  You may try to add those JARs manually to the classpath to get rid of the message.

Comment: How to add them manually? The output .exe file is still 42KB.

Comment: add slf4j-simple-version.jar and slf4j-api-version.jar to the classpath as you run the jar. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder to figure out the version check the depedencies of packr 1.1 in maven

Comment: In maven there's only version 1.0 I think

Comment: How should I add them into classpath? I am sorry, I am not familiar with this.

Comment: Check https://github.com/libgdx/packr/blob/master/pom.xml for other questions search here if you cant find a similar question post a new one.  There are many classpath questions here. Start with Packr to see if you can do it there if not check -classpath