# @GeneratedValue not working in JPA with oracle databse

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, oracle11g, annotations, spring-data-jpa

when I try to insert two objects into the table, instead of the primary key auto incrementing it is updating the first inserted object with the values of the second object.

I have a entity class called users.java

```
package com.company.entities;
// default package
// Generated Jul 16, 2014 2:33:35 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Users generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS", schema = "DOCTORASSIST")
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "users_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "users_seq", sequenceName="users_seq", allocationSize=1)
    private long userId;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String status;
    private Set<UserRoles> userRoleses = new HashSet<UserRoles>(0);

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Users(long userId, String username, String password, String status,
            Set<UserRoles> userRoleses) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.status = status;
        this.userRoleses = userRoleses;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
    public long getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }


    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", length = 45)
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", length = 100)
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "STATUS", length = 45)
    public String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "users")
    public Set<UserRoles> getUserRoleses() {
        return this.userRoleses;
    }

    public void setUserRoleses(Set<UserRoles> userRoleses) {
        this.userRoleses = userRoleses;
    }

}
```

I am trying to insert two users in to the database table with user_id as the primary key and auto increment the primary key value using @generated value

here is the test class

```
@ContextConfiguration
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class OrderPersistenceTests {

    @Autowired
    UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testSaveUser() throws Exception{
        Users users1 = new Users();
        Users users2 = new Users();
        //users1.setUserId();
        users1.setUsername("user1");
        users1.setPassword("password10");
        users1.setStatus("ACTIVE");
        usersRepository.saveAndFlush(users1);
        users2.setUsername("user2");
        users2.setPassword("password20");
        users2.setStatus("ACTIVE");

        usersRepository.saveAndFlush(users2);
    }


}
```

app-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- <mvc:annotation-driven /> <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" 
        /> -->

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="myDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
        <property name="username" value="doctorassist" />
        <property name="password" value="Thinkpad" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name='packagesToScan' value="com.company.entities" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" />
    <bean id="hibernateExceptionTranslator"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator" />


    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.company.repositories" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.*" />
    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myapp" /> -->

</beans>
```

here is the console log

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Hibernate: select users0_.USER_ID as USER1_10_0_, users0_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD10_0_, users0_.STATUS as STATUS10_0_, users0_.USERNAME as USERNAME10_0_ from DOCTORASSIST.USERS users0_ where users0_.USER_ID=?
Hibernate: insert into DOCTORASSIST.USERS (PASSWORD, STATUS, USERNAME, USER_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update DOCTORASSIST.USERS set PASSWORD=?, STATUS=?, USERNAME=? where USER_ID=?
```

users table  DDL

```
create table users(
user_id number(10) primary key not null,
username varchar2(45),
password varchar2(100),
status varchar2(45)
);
```

Comment: Your post saying only failure of slf4j class loading. Not relevant to inserting records. Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: The test is run against Oracle or an in-memory DB? Can you please add the SQL table ddl. I'd like to see the PK definition and any possible DEFAULT directive.

Comment: @VladMihalcea I added the DDL of the table. .. the test is run against Oracle DB

Comment: @suninsky that is the full stack trace.

Comment: Ok, so have you looked into this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder ???

Comment: @ANyarThar how is that related to my problem ?