# "Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"."

Tags: java, gwt, logging, slf4j

When I run my GWT module I get the following error message in the log:

```
Super Dev Mode starting up
   workDir: /Users/mg/Documents/GWT/test/build/work
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
   Loading Java files in test.mobile.
   Module setup completed in 24492 ms

The code server is ready at http://192.168.178.26:9876/
```

**What does it mean and how can I prevent it?**

Comment: Have your read the linked web page? SLF4J is only an API - so you have to add an Implementation to your project, too. See also: http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: As the message said: You have to add an implementation to the classpath of your project. E.g., download the the latest SLF4J zip [here](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html), unzip it and add `slf4j-simple-1.7.10.jar` to your path.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder ?

Comment: If you post an answer I can accept it.