# GATE - Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" error

Tags: slf4j, text-analysis, gate

I am using GATE for text analysis and when I load the TwitIE plugin I get the following stack of errors.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Reading POS tagger model from file:/C:/Program%20Files/GATE_Developer_8.4/plugins/Twitter/resources/pos/gate-EN-twitter.model ... warning: no language set, no open-class tags specified, and no closed-class tags specified; assuming ALL tags are open class tags done [3.1 sec].
```

I am very new to GATE and I would be very happy if someone could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think all the messages are just warnings, or does your app crash after that?

Comment: Concerning **SLF4J** - just follow the [link form the message](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder), there is a nice explanation and advice how to fix it.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7421612/1857897