# stanford NLP API error in java maven project

Tags: java, maven, stanford-nlp

I have been working on this project for a while. I'm using stanford NLP. I've added its dependency in my maven project. it used to work completely fine but now it shows this error: (I even downloaded similar project from git to find out if something is wrong done by me yet same message is displayed for that too. please let me know the problem)

```
Adding annotator tokenize
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:493)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:81)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:260)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:127)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:123)
        at CoreNlpExample.main(CoreNlpExample.java:17)
    Caused by: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:749)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:283)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:247)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:78)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:62)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:491)
        ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as either class path, filename or URL
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:419)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:744)
        ... 10 more
```

Comment: Include you code as well. I can see what cause the error.

Comment: here's the link to the project i'm using: https://github.com/TechPrimers/core-nlp-example

Comment: Did you update your maven project ?

Comment: yes...multiple times

Comment: I find it helpful to cut & paste error messages into Google.  I usually find that I'm not the first one to encounter a problem.  I did that for the pertinent bit in your stack trace and got lots back, including this: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the models jar in your classpath. You can either download this manually, or include it with maven via the instructions at https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html (replace version as appropriate):

```
<dependencies> <dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version> 
  </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier> 
  </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

Comment: i'm getting this kind of error now:SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: @Gurjotkaur read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder

Comment: @Lokesh i added the given dependencies too...but it does not help...same error yet again! any other solution please?

Comment: @Gurjotkaur In that case you can raise this issue on github .

Comment: @Gurjotkaur also try one more thing while updating check the force update of snapshot and releases. and update you maven once again.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you haven't given Java enough memory. Make sure to set -mx to a few gb.

Comment: i've now given it 3gb space and tried the solution of the mentioned link...but it doesnt solve anything