# Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" nothing works

Tags: java, slf4j, hikaricp

I'm coding at the moment a project for Minecraft but HikariCP doesn't work fully because of the slf4j. Nothing works I'm searching for two hours on the Internet but I don't get it. I have tried almost everything.

> 25.04 21:35:26 [Server] WARN SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   25.04 21:35:26 [Server] WARN SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>   25.04 21:35:26 [Server] WARN SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details.

```
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Set the version of slf4j to use

Comment: take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder

Comment: I've now this:https://hastebin.com/efajatiyop.xml