# Java Firebase Admin SDK - GoogleCredentials cannot be resolved

Tags: java, firebase-admin

I am trying to connect the Firebase Admin SDK to my Android project. Im only in the initial set up process right now but I keep getting this credentials error and I have no idea what the issue is.

[Main Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4tpA.png)

[--- Gradle Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wusna.png)

edit:

I added the OAuth2 dependency to the build.gradle.
`implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v1-rev142-1.23.0'`

 Now I am getting this error.

`SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.`

Comment: Please share your build files also for further investigation.

Comment: Gradle build has been added

Comment: So, oauth library should be added to your build as a dependency. No?

Comment: Can you execute `./gradlew build` command?

Comment: Added the Oauth dependency and now im getting a new error

Comment: You cannot use Admin SDK in an Android project. It is for back-end and server-side use only.

Comment: Anyway, the new error is because an slf4j logging binding is missing. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka im not adding the admin SDK directly inside the android studio code. This is a separate back-end entity that is part of the overall app project, i.e. front-end, back-end, database, etc.

Comment: @sanastasiadis YO thanks this solved the connection issue! Thanks a lot. I really wish they mentioned this stuff in the Firebase admin documentation.