# Selenium-Maven-Gauge template not running

Tags: getgauge

I am currently building off of the gauge-maven-selenium template and I have added my own spec and java class steps to test it. Unfortunately when I try to run using 'mvn clean test' it builds it just fine, but when trying to run it, it stops after :

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder

Comment: Thanks for responding! This did not help my problem. I'm still unable to execute my tests.

Comment: you need to add code for this to get help