# SLF4J: W/System.err: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: kotlin, slf4j

I am using ktor-wbsockets in my android app in Kotlin and I got this error. Could anyone please help me how do I import slf4j to my app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder)

Comment: No, I know there are a few similar questions, but I would like to know how import it in kotlin and gradle

Comment: The same way you would in java and gradle?

Comment: For example this answer to the previously linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43346247/3424746