# ERROR SpringApplication Application run failed java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner

Tags: java, spring

I'm actually trying to run a Spring application with Maven. Nevertheless, I've got the following error:

[image: Spring's error]

Don't be cruel with me, I'm actually a novice using StackOverflow and I'm learning how to use it, so I don't really know how to paste code so here is the project code:
https://github.com/zahrof/Moteur-recherche-bibliotheque.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or stack traces https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.13.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder

Comment: Thanks, it has debug a bit. Nevertheless I still cannot execute the CommandLineRunner...