# how to use slf4j in java agent when in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j, agent

Springboot uses JarLauncher so that a nested jar is supported.
But the agent code do not load class by using JarLauncher because it executes before the main method.As a result, the console will print

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

--update
This issue can reproduce the problem.
https://github.com/libinglong/skywalking-threadpool-agent/issues/2

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder)

Comment: @Sathia yes, I use maven.

Comment: @sas No, it does not match my problem.