# slf4j Errors and will not log Java/Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

When I run my backend application I am getting `slf4j` errors and nothing being logged to my console with log4j.  This is only on my machine and the same application is able to be run on the same model MacBook with no errors and logs showing.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder

Comment: Have you gone to the URL in the error?  It explains what is wrong.