# Java - Selenium Firefoxdriver does not start when using .jar file

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, slf4j

When I create a `.jar` file and want to start the `firefox webdriver` I get an Error. It works if I run it in `VS-Code`.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Build info: version: '4.1.0', revision: '87802e897b'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP', ip: 'IP', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:230)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:164)
        at hegahelperjava.Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

I already added SLF4j to my maven dependecies like they said here: [java - SLF4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder)

Here a snippet to recreate the problem:

```
//selenium
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
//webdrivermanager
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String driversPath = "PATHTODRIVER";
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().cachePath(driversPath).avoidOutputTree().setup();
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding the NOOP jar to your libs.  You can get it here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.7.9/

Comment: changed nothing

Comment: yeah, I wouldn't think the noop warning would cause it to not run...  I would check into webdrivermanager's output.  You're setting the cachePath to something, so maybe check permissions and that sort of thing.  ( if (!driver.canExecute())
           {
    ...
  
            thisDriver.setExecutable (true, true);
           } Your exception doesn't list the driver version which seems unusual.  Maybe also switch to using latest version 4 Selenium and Java 8.

Comment: Oh xD yeah Selenium 4.1.4 does work out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a conclusion.
If something does not work, try to update your `dependencies` fixes most problems

In This Case `selenium 4.1.0` did not allow to execute `firefoxdriver` when the app is packed into a jar. It works fine with `selenium 4.1.4`.