# I can't understand why am I getting this error when I even don't have "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" in my dependency

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I put below my results that I am having. Can someone help me to figure where I am making a mistake please?

```
enter code here
```

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"

```
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.romance</groupId>
<artifactId>romance</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Jun 28, 2022 9:33:31 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/zarinabakchieva/Desktop/romance/chromedriver" (in directory "."): error=86, Bad CPU type in executable)

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Zarinas-MacBook-Air.local', ip: '2601:647:5e80:d7c0:0:0:0:3ada%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '11.0.11'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

```
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
at MainClass.testMainPage(MainClass.java:11)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:677)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:221)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:962)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:806)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:601)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:433)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:427)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:387)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:16690/status] to be available after 20014 ms
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
... 36 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
... 37 more

Comment: You may not have added it, but you should because one of your libraries/dependencies appears to require it. Visit the link given in the error which specifies the files you are missing: "This warning message is reported when the org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class could not be loaded into memory. This happens when no appropriate SLF4J binding could be found on the class path. Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder)

Comment: @sorifiend thank you for replying. How do I have to add it? I am new here and I am at the beginning of my journey. Sorry for asking too many question?

Comment: @ZBakchieva Take a look at the link above from tgdavies, the accepted answer shows you which dependencies to add to your project, just copy it and enter the correct version number as described in the post.

Comment: @sorifiend should I add to existed dependency or I need to delete them and then add the one that tgdavies says because I have selenium and testNG library and I am not where to add it and which one exactly

Comment: <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: So I added but I still getting this error: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Jun 30, 2022 1:48:03 AM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/zarinabakchieva/Desktop/romance/chromedriver" (in directory "."): error=86, Bad CPU type in executable)

Comment: Looks like you have now worked out how to solve your original error which is great, but now it sounds like you have added a dependency and supporting files for another operating system/architecture. Make sure the library and files for SLF4J match the device architecture (You can't use Windows libraries on an Android device or a Mac for example). At this point you will be best to make a new question with all the details and include your updated/current dependancies