Can't find compatible version of logback
In my project I am using slf4j for logging.
If I include dependency on logback-classic = "1.2.13" or earlier, I get an error message that no SLF4J providers found and that it is defaulted to no-logging.
If I read the referred pages, it suggests to add newer dependency.
But If I add dependency on newer version of logback, it throws an exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
How to solve?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder or any of the many, many other SO questions about this.

You should of course use a new dependency. For one thing, that has a vulnerability as do many other early versions. Try 1.4.12. All you need is logback-classic as a logging dependency

You shouldn't declare these versions in a Spring Boot project, since the compatible versions are already set through spring-boot-dependencies.

You shouldn't declare these versions in a Spring Boot project, since the compatible versions are already set through spring-boot-dependencies. You can open the dedicated POM and will find all dependencies tested by the Spring team, their compatible versions already set.
In case you wanna use Log4J2 instead of the default logger Logback, the dependencies in a Maven project are typically set as follows:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    ....

</dependencies>

